# Group by and aggregate functions

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to use union and group by with aggregate functions, but all attempts either result in missing rows or incorrect data. Below are two queries that produce the data I need, now i just need to unite them

Here is a sample SQL Dump on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/yds4ZpCP)

SQL Query #1:

```
SELECT o.id as order_id, SUM(price * quantity) as total_prod, 0 as total_inst
FROM orders as o, orders_product_line as opl, products as p
WHERE opl.order_id = o.id
AND p.id = opl.product_id
GROUP BY o.id
```

Result for Query #1

```
+----------+------------+------------+
| order_id | total_prod | total_inst |
+----------+------------+------------+
|        1 |       4200 |          0 |
|        2 |      40000 |          0 |
|        3 |    3600000 |          0 |
|        4 |      44500 |          0 |
|        5 |    1229800 |          0 |
|        6 |   45000000 |          0 |
+----------+------------+------------+
```

SQL Query #2:

```
SELECT o.id as order_id, 0 as total_prod, SUM(rate * hours) as total_inst
FROM orders as o, orders_installation_line as oil, installations as i
WHERE oil.order_id = o.id
AND i.id = oil.intallation_id
GROUP BY order_id
```

Result for Query #2:

```
+----------+------------+------------+
| order_id | total_prod | total_inst |
+----------+------------+------------+
|        1 |          0 |       4675 |
|        2 |          0 |     255000 |
|        3 |          0 |      18880 |
|        4 |          0 |        600 |
|        5 |          0 |       3540 |
+----------+------------+------------+
```

Here is my attempt at using union for the two tables

```
SELECT o.id as order_id, SUM(price * quantity) as total_prod, 0 as total_inst FROM orders as o, orders_product_line as opl, products as p WHERE opl.order_id = o.id AND p.id = opl.product_id GROUP BY o.id
UNION ALL
SELECT o.id as order_id, 0 as total_prod, SUM(rate * hours) as total_inst FROM orders as o,  orders_installation_line as oil, installations as i WHERE oil.order_id = o.id AND i.id = oil.intallation_id GROUP BY order_id
```

And the result

```
+----------+------------+------------+
| order_id | total_prod | total_inst |
+----------+------------+------------+
|        1 |       4200 |          0 |
|        2 |      40000 |          0 |
|        3 |    3600000 |          0 |
|        4 |      44500 |          0 |
|        5 |    1229800 |          0 |
|        6 |   45000000 |          0 |
|        1 |          0 |       4675 |
|        2 |          0 |     255000 |
|        3 |          0 |      18880 |
|        4 |          0 |        600 |
|        5 |          0 |       3540 |
+----------+------------+------------+
```

Lastly, Here is my attempt at using union after reading other answers on stack overflow:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
SELECT o.id as order_id, SUM(price * quantity) as total_prod, 0 as total_inst
FROM orders as o, orders_product_line as opl, products as p
WHERE opl.order_id = o.id
AND p.id = opl.product_id
GROUP BY o.id

UNION ALL

SELECT o.id as order_id, 0 as total_prod, SUM(rate * hours) as total_inst
FROM orders as o, orders_installation_line as oil, installations as i
WHERE oil.order_id = o.id
AND i.id = oil.intallation_id
GROUP BY order_id
) Q
GROUP BY Q.order_id
```

And the result of this last union:

```
+----------+------------+------------+
| order_id | total_prod | total_inst |
+----------+------------+------------+
|        1 |       4200 |          0 |
|        2 |      40000 |          0 |
|        3 |    3600000 |          0 |
|        4 |      44500 |          0 |
|        5 |    1229800 |          0 |
|        6 |   45000000 |          0 |
+----------+------------+------------+
```

What am I missing? I need that last column `total_inst` to show values. This is the result I am looking for:

```
+----------+------------+------------+
| order_id | total_prod | total_inst |
+----------+------------+------------+
|        1 |       4200 |       4675 |
|        2 |      40000 |     255000 |
|        3 |    3600000 |      18880 |
|        4 |      44500 |        600 |
|        5 |    1229800 |       3540 |
|        6 |   45000000 |          0 |
+----------+------------+------------+
```

Comment: Can you show what would be your desired result? On the first query you set the `total_inst` as 0. Edit your post with your tables structure and, the attempts you made plus your desired result. It will be a lot easier to help you.

Comment: Edited to show the Results I'm after. @JorgeCampos, `total_inst` (total installation revenue) is 0 in sql 1 and `total_prod` (total product revenue) is 0 in sql 2 because orders can have products and/or installations, and I want the results to be able to display 0 for `total_inst` and 0 `total_prod` as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Group By's are right… but I don't think you want a union. Try this instead:

```
select q1.order_id, q1.total_prod, q2.total_inst from 
(SELECT o.id as order_id, SUM(price * quantity) as total_prod, 0 as total_inst FROM orders as o, orders_product_line as opl, products as p WHERE opl.order_id = o.id AND p.id = opl.product_id GROUP BY o.id) q1, 
(SELECT o.id as order_id, 0 as total_prod, SUM(rate * hours) as total_inst FROM orders as o,  orders_installation_line as oil, installations as i WHERE oil.order_id = o.id AND i.id = oil.intallation_id GROUP BY order_id) q2
where q1.order_id = q2.order_id
```

EDIT: The above query will only retrieve order_ids which are returned by BOTH inner queries. To include order_id 6, you would need a **LEFT JOIN**. However, that would not get records that might exist in the results from q2 but not in the results from q1 (the opposite case). A **FULL JOIN** would do this, but my understanding is that these are not implemented in MySQL. They can be emulated though, as explained here: [Full Outer Join in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/full-outer-join-in-mysql?rq=1)

```
select q1.order_id, q1.total_prod, q2.total_inst from 
(SELECT o.id as order_id, SUM(price * quantity) as total_prod, 0 as total_inst FROM orders as o, orders_product_line as opl, products as p WHERE opl.order_id = o.id AND p.id = opl.product_id GROUP BY o.id) q1
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT o.id as order_id, 0 as total_prod, SUM(rate * hours) as total_inst FROM orders as o,  orders_installation_line as oil, installations as i WHERE oil.order_id = o.id AND i.id = oil.intallation_id GROUP BY order_id) q2
ON q1.order_id = q2.order_id
UNION
select q1.order_id, q1.total_prod, q2.total_inst from 
(SELECT o.id as order_id, SUM(price * quantity) as total_prod, 0 as total_inst FROM orders as o, orders_product_line as opl, products as p WHERE opl.order_id = o.id AND p.id = opl.product_id GROUP BY o.id) q1 
RIGHT JOIN 
(SELECT o.id as order_id, 0 as total_prod, SUM(rate * hours) as total_inst FROM orders as o,  orders_installation_line as oil, installations as i WHERE oil.order_id = o.id AND i.id = oil.intallation_id GROUP BY order_id) q2
ON q1.order_id = q2.order_id
```

**FINAL EDIT**: Here's is a working SQLFiddle of another approach. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/deff12/12/0

Comment: this ALSMOT produces the result i am looking for, but fails to show orders that have a 0 in the `total_prod` or `total_inst` columns. For example, with this sql, order_id 6 does not get returned (see edited question for the desired result)

Comment: Ahhh then you need an outer join, rather than the default inner join produced by the where clause "where q1.order_id = q2.order_id." I'll update the above answer.

Comment: Matt, your edited query does produce the desired results, but it does not seem ideal (perhaps not the most optimal route). I will keep having a play with it, if no one else chimes in with a working query that is shorter, I will mark your answer as correct.

Comment: There is another way to do it (there's almost always another way), but I don't know off the top of my head if it would perform better or worse. I'll update again.

Comment: Thanks for your continued efforts matt, I aded a link to a sql dump of the schema and sample data. Your most recent edit produces the same results as your first (missing row if 0 or null)

Comment: Ahhh good call. Forgot the JOINS that were the original issue. :) Edited again… hopefully for the last time!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Matt, what you need here is a join/cartesian product and not a union. Try:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT o.id as order_id, SUM(price * quantity) as total_prod, FROM orders as o, orders_product_line as opl, products as p WHERE opl.order_id = o.id AND p.id = opl.product_id GROUP BY o.id) as q1 NATURAL JOIN
(SELECT o.id as order_id, SUM(rate * hours) as total_inst FROM orders as o,  orders_installation_line as oil, installations as i WHERE oil.order_id = o.id AND i.id = oil.intallation_id GROUP BY order_id) as q2;
```

1st EDIT:
Okay. So basically, if id is in orders_product_line but not orders_installation_line then we need to insert a tuple with the id, the value of total_prod and a value of 0 for total_inst. Is that correct? So try something like this:

```
(SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT o.id as order_id, SUM(price * quantity) as total_prod, FROM orders as o, orders_product_line as opl, products as p WHERE opl.order_id = o.id AND p.id = opl.product_id GROUP BY o.id) as q1 NATURAL JOIN
(SELECT o.id as order_id, SUM(rate * hours) as total_inst FROM orders as o,  orders_installation_line as oil, installations as i WHERE oil.order_id = o.id AND i.id = oil.intallation_id GROUP BY order_id) as q2)
UNION 
(SELECT o.id as order_id, SUM(price * quantity) as total_prod, 0 as total_inst FROM orders as o, orders_product_line as opl, products as p WHERE opl.order_id = o.id AND p.id = opl.product_id AND opl.order_id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM orders_installation_line) GROUP BY o.id)
UNION
(SELECT o.id as order_id, 0 as total_prod, SUM(rate * hours) as total_inst FROM orders as o,  orders_installation_line as oil, installations as i WHERE oil.order_id = o.id AND i.id = oil.intallation_id AND oil.order_id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM orders_product_line) GROUP BY order_id);
```

How does that work? It's probably very suboptimal, but hopefully it gets the result.

Comment: This too ALMOST produces the result I'm looking for, same problem as Matt's first query (missing rows when 0 value in total_prod/total_inst)